# FInd all analytic functions in the Complex Field

Tags: complex-analysis

Find all analytic functions $f:\mathbb{C}-\{0\} \to \mathbb{C}$ such that $f(z)=f(2z),\forall z \in \mathbb{C}-\{0\}$

Comment: Well, in the exam I tried with Liouville Theorem's, but, this only works when the function is entire, moreover, i tried with compose whit other entire functions, but, nothing.

Comment: Great! I can say that it is related to Liouville theorem. Did you also learn that a bounded analytic function $f: \mathbb C \setminus \{0\} \to \mathbb C$ can be extended to $\mathbb C$?

Comment: mmm no, can you teach me ? Or please can you make the problem?, I've been trying all day with this.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is that $f$ has to be a constant function.

First of all, the condition $f(z) = f(2z)$ would imply that $f$ is a bounded analytic function defined on $\mathbb C\setminus \{0\}$ (though it's intuitively clear, you might still need to write down a proof).

But it turns out that for a bounded analytic function $f: D\setminus \{a\} \to \mathbb C$, one can always extend it to an analytic function $f: D \to \mathbb C$.

(The wiki page give a decent proof of this fact: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Removable_singularity )

So in our case, $f: \mathbb C\to \mathbb C$ is bounded analytic, and by Liouville's theorem, it is constant.

Comment: Oh ! hahaha the Professor taught this theorem the class before the exam xD.
Thanks!

Comment: @Inzit: You are welcome.